# **/ not working with a mounted volume

Tags: bash, osx, wildcards, cp

I'm trying to recursively extract a set of .jpgs from a mounted volume using SMB1, to a folder on my computer. Here's what I've got:

```
cp -a **/97*.jpg /Users/.../All_Covers
```

This works as long as my current directory, and the images, are somewhere on my computer, but as soon as I `cd` to the mounted volume where the directories holding the actual images are, it fails, giving me a:

```
cp: **/97*.jpg: No such file or directory
```

Why is this failing? Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you do `ls` on the files, do they appear as `.jpg` or `.JPG`? Sometimes case insensitivity doesn't work as expected, though I don't see why it would make a difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man bash`:

```
globstar
                  If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and  sub‐
                  directories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.
```

In other words, if you have cd'd to the directory with the jpgs, then none will match because `**/97*.jpg` only matches jpgs in a subdirectory.

**Workaround**:  Use `find`:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec cp -a -t destination/ {} +
```

This finds all `*.jpg` files at any depth under the current directory (`.`) and copies them to `destination/`.

The option `-t dir` tells `cp` to copy files to destination `dir`.  If your `cp` does not support that, there is a workaround:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec cp -a {} destination/ \;
```

This is less 'efficient' than the prior version because `cp` is run on every file (`{}`) rather than just once for all the filenames that can be made to fit on a command line (`{} +`).

Comment: I should clarify, from where I'm cd'ing to, the jpgs are still several layers deep, in hundreds of different folders.

Comment: @user56278  On my machine (Linux), I tested it and it works as documented.  OSX versions, though, are sometimes curiously different. I just updated the answer with a workaround.

Comment: I used the workaround suggested and got -t thrown back at me as an illegal option. I tried it without that option, and it simply gave me the usage prompt for cp. What does that option do in Linux?

Comment: @user56278 OK.  The answer is updated with that info and another workaround.

Comment: Fantastic! You're missing a `\;` at the end, but that was the ticket. Many thanks.

Comment: @user56278 Glad it worked.  Typo fixed.